# Elaboration needed on a section of a published paper about dictionary learning

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I will be doing my master thesis on dictionary learning, and I am trying to understand basic concepts of the subject reading the following paper:

> [K-SVD: An Algorithm for Designing Overcomplete Dictionaries for Sparse Representation](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~elad/publications/journals/2004/32_KSVD_IEEE_TSP.pdf)

In the following lines there are two conclusions or results which I don't understand well:

> We now turn to the second, and slightly more involved, process of updating the dictionary together with the nonzero coefficients. Assume that both $D$ and $X$ are fixed and we put in question only one column in the dictionary $d_k$ and the coefficients that correspond to it, the $k$th row in $X$, denoted as $x_T^{k}$ (this is not the vector which is the $k$th column in $X$). [...]
>   **We have decomposed the multiplication $DX$ to the sum of $k$ rank-$1$ matrices.** Among those, $k-1$ terms are assumed fixed, and one—the $k$th—remains in question. The matrix stands for the error for all the examples when the $k$th atom is removed.

Now my questions are:

- In the multiplication $DX$, the paper is talking about multiplying columns of $D$ by rows of $X$, is this mathematically correct? I was taught that we multiply rows of the first matrix by the columns of the second one, isn't it so?
- What is meant by the sentence in bold, "sum of $k$ rank-$1$ matrices"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix product $DX$ is indeed the product of the $i$'th row of $D$ and the $j$'th column of $X$.  This is talking about the same multiplication from a slightly different perspective.  Each element in the $k$'th column of $D$ gets multiplied by each element in the $k$'th row of $X$, and the results put in different entries of the product.
If $D$ is $m \times n$ and $X$ is $n \times p$, $DX$ is the sum of the 
$n$ matrices $d_k x_T^k$, $k = 1 \ldots n$, each of which is an $m \times p$ matrix that has rank $1$. Thus $DX$ is the sum of $n$ rank-$1$ matrices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still don't understand the answer to my second question.

Comment: For example, take $D = \pmatrix{d_{11}  & d_{12}\cr d_{21} & d_{22}\cr}$ and $X = \pmatrix{x_{11} & x_{12}\cr x_{21} & x_{22}\cr}$.  Then 
$$DX = \pmatrix{d_{11} x_{11} & d_{11} x_{12}\cr d_{21} x_{11} & d_{21} x_{12}\cr} + \pmatrix{d_{12} x_{21} & d_{12} x_{22}\cr d_{22} x_{21} & d_{22} x_{22}}$$
is the sum of two rank-1 matrices.  (Well, to be more precise, rank $\le 1$: it is possible that all entries could be $0$)